# How to properly copy a linked list using copy constructor in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list, copy-constructor

I can't properly use the copy constructor to make a copy of `LinkedList`.

Consider this example:

```
public class LinkedList {
    
    public class Node {
        Node next;
        int val;
        Node(int val) {
            this.val = val;
            next = null;
        }
    }
    public Node head;
    public Node current;
    public LinkedList() {
        
    }
    
    
    public LinkedList(LinkedList another) {
        this.head = another.head;
        this.current = another.current;
    }
    
    public boolean empty() {
        return head == null;
    }
    
    public void insert(int e) {
    
        if (empty()) {
            head = current = new Node(e);
            return;
        }
        Node currNode = new Node(e);
        Node tmp = current;
        tmp.next = currNode;
        current = currNode;
        

    }
    
    public void display() {
        Node currNode = head;
        while (currNode != null) {
            System.out.println(currNode.val);
            currNode = currNode.next;
        }
    }
}
```

I made a copy of linked list using copy constructor, code in main is below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        LinkedList ls = new LinkedList();
        ls.insert(5);
        ls.insert(6);
        ls.insert(7);
        
        LinkedList another = new LinkedList(ls);
        
        another.display();
        another.insert(0);
        ls.display(); // expected output is 5 6 7 
    }
}
```

The output of the code is `5 6 7 5 7 6 0`, however I expected it to be `5 6 7` because I made copy, it won't affect `ls`. What's going in? How to fix that to get the expected output?

Comment: Your copy constructor is doing a "sort of shallow copy", so that the actual list of nodes is not being copied, hence changes to "another" affect "ls", too.   You need to do a "deep copy" where you copy each of the nodes in ls.

Comment: Hi, you've created a new LinkedList, but you've added Node object references from the existing LinkedList to the new one. Those existing Node objects will grow in both LinkedLists as the references are now shared.

Comment: I'd consider adding a clone method that returns a `Node` object. Start from the head `Node` and ask each connected `Node` to create a cloned copy of itself, link each `Node` and then finally return the copy of the head 'Node'.

Comment: @MarkLavin Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
public LinkedList(const LinkedList& another) {
    this->head = this->current = another.copy()
}

private LinkedList copy( const LinkedList& another ) {
    Node last_node = null;
    Node new_first = null;
    for ( Node next_node = another->head; next_node != null; 
          next_node = next_node->Next ) {
        Node new_node = new Node( next_node );
        if ( new_first == null )
            new_first = new_node;
        if ( last_node != null )
            last_node.Next = new_node
        last_node = next_node;
     }
     return new_first;
}
```

NOTE that I also changed the signature of the copy constructor; in general,
the argument should be a `const` reference.  Also, my simple solution
contains a storage leak, since it isn't deleting the current nodes of "this" before copying from `another`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to stackoverflow community

Here is a solution to your post:

You can modify the LinkedList constructor as below:

```
    public LinkedList(LinkedList another) {
        Node previous = another.head;
        Node temp = null;
        // represent a reference to the head of the new linkedList
        Node first = null;
    while (previous != null) {
        Node node = new Node(previous.val);
        if (first == null) {
            first = node;
            temp = first;
        } else {
            temp.next = node;
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        previous = previous.next;
    }

        // set the head
        this.head = first;
        // Temp hold a reference of the last node of the another passed as parameter
        this.current = temp;

}
```

I added comments to the main method to show the linked list content before and after insertion:

```
        public static void main(String [] args) {
        LinkedList ls = new LinkedList();
        ls.insert(5);
        ls.insert(6);
        ls.insert(7);
        System.out.println("------------ begin display initial list ls");
        ls.display();
        System.out.println("------------ end display initial list ls");

        LinkedList another = new LinkedList(ls);

        System.out.println("------------ begin display another list before insert");
        another.display();
        System.out.println("------------ end display another list before insert");
        System.out.println("------------ Insert 0 in another linked list");

        another.insert(0);

        System.out.println("------------ begin display another list after insert");
        another.display();
        System.out.println("------------ end display another list after insert");
        System.out.println("--------Initial list must not be modified------------");
        ls.display(); // expected output is 5 6 7
        System.out.println("--------end------------");
    }
```

This is the result in console

```
 ------------ begin display initial list ls
 5
 6
 7
 ------------ end display initial list ls
 ------------ begin display another list before insert
 5
 6
 7
 ------------ end display another list before insert
 ------------ Insert 0 in another linked list
 ------------ begin display another list after insert
 5
 6
 7
 0
 ------------ end display another list after insert
 --------Initial list must not be modified------------
 5
 6
 7
 --------end------------
```

We have the expected result.